# How to emulate slow postgres db

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds, ubuntu-18.04

I have a postgres database that I did not create in AWS/RDS.  Specifically it's the one of the replicas of the production database that i'm accessing.  Both production and replica are on a db.t2.xlarge

I have a handful of queries that run slow on this system taking 10 to 30 seconds each to run.

*(Addendum, I have queries which run slow on a production site, but they don't always run slow.  My guess as to why they run fast sometimes is that they are being cached.  My reason for wanting to have this database local is so that i could clear the cache between each test to ensure a slow query every time)*

In order to debug I've created a local copy of this database (the dump file was 11 gigs, not sure if that is big or not), however whenever I run the queries locally they run in about half a second.

My local postgres db (version 10) is running with all default settings.  My question is which settings should i tweak to make my system run like the one on AWS? (aka slow)

My local system is a Dell Inspiron 5570 with 32 gigs of ram running Ubuntu 18.04 natively so i am assuming this is much more powerful than whatever AWS has allotted our RDS machine.

More info on my local system:
CPU: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-8550U CPU @ 1.80GHz

Comment: First thing you should check is the kind of disk your AWS/RDS is using - check the IOPS settings. The disk makes a huge difference. You can also check the WAL settings. See if there any weird looking messages in the postgres log.

Comment: Not sure if this is exactly what you are referring to: Storage Encryption Not Enabled, Storage type General Purpose (SSD), IOPS - 40 GiB, Storage autoscaling enabled, Maximum storage threshold 100 GiB.  I get this from the Configuration tab, not sure where else to look.

Comment: max_wal_senders:10, max_wal_size: 1024, min_wal_size:80  this is probably more what you mean i suspect

Comment: @jjanes good point, but spinning up new server involves paying some sort of fees which in turn involves me getting approval from someone at work

Comment: How are you running these queries in AWS - using postgres CLI or you are connecting some tool such as DBVisualizer etc? If not CLI can you try in CLI and check the time it takes. BTW, when was the last time you ran VACUUM - for more info check: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/sql-vacuum.html

Comment: I am using DBVisualizer but I could use the CLI as well (dbvis gives me a time for total execution).  As for VACUUM this is the first i've heard of it (i'm fairly new to postgres) I will look into this.   Note: my original problem that i was trying to solve is that my queries run slow, but only sometimes, i figure they run fast other times because of caching which i wanted to mess with on my local (and not production)

Comment: I am not sure if you can use Performance Insights with that instance type.

Comment: It can be very hard or impossible to configure different hardware to behave as if it were the same.  An easier way to get some insight into what is going on is to turn track_io_timing on and then get an EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS, TIMING OFF) of the same query on both systems.  Also, can you tell if your CPU credit balance on the t2 instance is depleted?

Comment: @jjanes I agree with what you said, but why `TIMING OFF`?

Comment: On some hardware and kernels, TIMING ON can slow things down by several fold, distorting the thing it is trying to measure.  Usually this is only on older hardware and kernels, but I have noticed AWS VMs to be susceptible to this problem.  But not predictably so. It might depend on what class of machine, or what your co-tenants are doing.